# When a layout is nested inside another layout, does it inherit the params of the parent?

Tags: android, layout

Ok so imagine a situation where you have the main layout as `LinearLayout` (which supports `layout_weight`) and inside it you have nested `RelativeLayout` (which does not support `layout_weight`).

Now since the `RelativeLayout` is nested inside `LinearLayout`, will it be able to use `layout_weight` ? And if the case was reversed (Linear inside Relative), will `LinearLayout` be able to use `layout_below`, `layout_toParentLeft`, etc ?

Comment: no, no no no no n no nono

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic That's a lot of *no* s and frustration :p

Comment: wont let me write a comment with 2 letters only :D but seriously, they dont inherit :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now since the RelativeLayout is nested inside LinearLayout, will it be able to use layout_weight ?

No. Since `RelativeLayout` is nested inside `LinearLayout` it can be given a `weight` to be weighted inside the `LinearLayout` but it does not inherit the property of `weightSum` to hand out to children.

> And if the case was reversed (Linear inside Relative), will LinearLayout be able to use layout_below, layout_toParentLeft, etc ?

Yes, you are inside of a `RelativeLayout` so any child can be given those properties. However, any child inside of that nested `LinearLayout` can not use the properties of `RelativeLayout` as in your example.

[WeighSum Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setWeightSum%28float%29)

> a number greater than 0.0f, or a number lower than or equals to 0.0f
>   if the weight sum should be computed from the children's
>   layout_weight"

`android:weightSUme="aNumber"` can be used to "sum" the weight of the children. If all the childrens sums will add up to 1 then you don't need this property. As I recently learned from @RomainGuy through a discussion with @Squonk, it is really only needed if they won't equal 1 and you want some empty space in your `layout`. Otherwise, the cpu will determine what the `weightSum` will be.

Comment: What I mean is, if I have a `LinearLayout` **which has** `RelativeLayout` **which has** `EditText`. Can `EditText` use `layout-weight` ?

Comment: Ah .. so immediate child can use properties. Children of children can not ! :-)

Comment: If the `LinearLayout` in your example is the parent, then no but the `RelativeLayout` can, which I think you understand.

Comment: Immediate child can use properties associated with the parent but does not inherit the ability to dole out those properties...if that makes sens, what :D

Comment: To put it in human context -- Father can get property from grandpa but can not hand it to children. *what a douche!*

Comment: The simple answer to your question, as everyone pointed out, is no. But I wanted to make sure that you understood the difference of using and inheriting the properties so hopefully I didn't confuse you more.

Comment: Go on... you now have a very simple analogy using which you can explain this complex situation !! :-D

Comment: I think you have it! The father will talk back to the grandpa but the grandchild will respect the grandpa's authority and not step into his territory

Comment: The grandpa can hand out duties (properties to use) to the father but the child cannot handle those chores. He must get his orders from his father

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is not very complicated. I can synthesize it in two letters: NO